# What is the name of this temple on Taekwondo educational videos

Tags: tae-kwon-do, identification

Might be irrelevant but I don't know where to ask other than here. What is the name of this temple and the mountain behind it on Taekwondo forms educational videos:

[image: Temple and mountain on Taekwondo educational videos]

Is this temple of any importance regarding Martial arts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be **Gyeongbokgung** in Seoul

Other than being the Royal residence during the Joseon dynasty (original palace destroyed by the Japanese and rebuilt recently) it doesn't particularly have any martial arts importance.

see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyeongbokgung) and [Visit Korea website](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/ATR/SI_EN_3_1_1_1.jsp?cid=264337) for more information.

Comment: I'm curious, did you do an image search or were you familiar with it already? I did some searches of my own to little avail and I'm always interested in honing my craft.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Taegeuk is WT - which meant it was likely linked to the kukkiwon - Doing a search for "kukkiwon temple" this building and mountain appear in some searches - then a bit of searching around on those pages for the location found the palace name.

Comment: Here is a more direct shot without people. The railings and side panels match very closely, and there are more pictures down the page as well. https://thesoulofseoul.net/2016/08/15/gyeongbokgung-palace-a-step-by-step-guide-to-missing-the-crowds/